# flex error message label

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm using flex for a Cirrus p2p video application. When I press "CALL" and the other Client isn't connected the error message is a popup message that says "[object Object]". I'm trying to display "Call failed to {calleeInput.text}" or anything for that matter. This is what I already have in my code (it might be best to view the pastebin below... I'm use to php and know little to nothing about flex... I just need to fix this issue):

```
        <s:HGroup includeIn="CallFailed" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Label text="Call failed to {calleeInput.text}" color="0xffffff"/>
        <s:Button label="HANGUP" click="onHangup()" styleName="buttonStyle"/>
    </s:HGroup>
```

Screenshot:  http://imgur.com/DLf2et2

Full Code (too long for stackoverflow): http://pastebin.com/diDrvn92

Edit: What information is needed to help assist me? Sorry I'm still stuck.

Update: I tried  but it didn't help

Comment: I think the problem is that it initializes that text field before there is any actual text in the calleeInput field. Have you tried setting the text via ActionScript, at the time the actual pop-up comes up?

Comment: My knowledge of flex is limited as I'm far more familiar with PHP. At what line of the code are you referring to in the pastebin?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, user3617188?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not an answer but need some clarification

I don't understand very well what are you trying to do, but `Responder` defines two functions, one if the server success and returns something and the other one if there's some error.

The functions will receive an `Object` as parameter in first case the result and in the other the fault from the server (exception)

You can trace it using

```
public function rejectCall(faultObj:String):void {
   trace(faultObj);
   currentState = CallReady;
}
```

The parameter you are using in `NetConnection.call` is not for the responder, it's for the `NetConnection`

Comment: This is a RTMFP flex script.

Comment: I simply cannot understand your suggestion but I do appreciate it. I tried revising the post above, perhaps that helps. Thanks.